# Excluding a directory from Git in Atom

Tags: git, codeigniter, atom-editor

I am just starting to use Git, and know that Atom has built in support.

Every time I refresh my site in the browser a number of logfiles are added to Unstaged Changes section in Atom.

I'm developing on CodeIgnitor. The problem folder is **writable/debugbar/**

I have this line in the .gitignore file of my app's root directory

```
writable/debugbar/*
```

How do I stop atom / git including these files?

Thanks

Comment: Were these files committed prior to adding them to your `.gitignore`?

Comment: I don't think so. I think I may have solved it by removing the *

Comment: If I remember correctly, you only need to provide the `*` when you want to specify exceptions to that rule

Comment: Ahhh okay, that makes sense (sort of). Thanks mate